# Substr in mongodb aggregate in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following command line mongodb query:

```
db.getCollection('Data').aggregate([
{'$project' : {"_id":"$_id",
           "g":"$g",
           "value": {'$substr':["$g",0,4]},
       }
}])
```

The result of this query is:

```
{
  "result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : NumberLong(1),
        "g" : "1383,09,1,2000",
        "value" : "1383"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : NumberLong(2),
        "g" : "1499,06,1,1",
        "value" : "1499"
    }, 

  ],
  "ok" : 1.0000000000000000,
  "$gleStats" : {
    "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
    "electionId" : ObjectId("564d7df200e15758444e9a7d")
  }
}
```

Now I want to use this query in a php file.

Especially how can I use $substr within $project with aggregate in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`MongoCollection::aggregate`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php)  method

```
$pipeline = array(
    '$project' => array(
        'g' => '$g',
        'value' => array('$substr' => array('$g', 0,4))
    )
);

$results = $collection->aggregate($pipeline)
```